# How can I log the IP addresses of SMB login attempts?

Tags: macos, smb, logs

I want to automatically ban IP address which attempt to login to my file server unauthorized.

I can log SSH login attempts **including IP address** in macOS to a syslog format file for further processing with fail2ban like so:

```
log stream --predicate '(process == "sshd")' --style syslog --level info --type=log >> /opt/local/var/log/logstreams/sshd.log
```

However, the smbd process doesn't seem to log IP by default. How can I achieve the above for smbd?

Answer (score 1):

You could fire up and configure the BSD packetfilter - create a rule that will match incoming 'rogue' SMB requests, and in that rule use the `log` keyword which will cause all packets matching that rule to be, er, logged.

Walkthough here: https://blog.neilsabol.site/post/quickly-easily-adding-pf-packet-filter-firewall-rules-macos-osx/

In-depth explanation here: http://marckerr.com/a-simple-guild-to-the-mac-pf-firewall/

Explanation of the pf logging function here:https://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/logging.html

Setting up pfctl anchors for a protocol:
https://ikawnoclast.com/systems/firewall/mac-os-x-pf-firewall/

Comment: Can you add the specific rule(s) required directly to your question? The linked pages have a lot of useful information but don't seem to explain how to accomplish what you describe in the first paragraph.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't helpful. I know how to configure pf. Getting IP addresses of unauthorized login attempts is the issue.

Comment: Ok, sorry; can you still use `pfctl` anchors to log and block after a specified number of attempts on a particular protocol?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible or not. I'm using fail2ban for blocking because it allows me to exponentially increase ban time of repeated attempts.

Comment: Not sure that anchor tables will allow you to increase ban time - from what I understand, it just outright bans the IP for good.